Can a B-707 recover from a spin?
There was an incident in 1959 involving a Boeing 707 on a training flight near Paris, France where a badly executed MCA demo reportedly resulted in the plane entering a spin, had an engine torn off the aircraft, and then recovered to level flight.  This is described in https://aviation-safety.net/asndb/334056, which in turn cites a UPI report reprinted in the New York Times.  The article is https://nyti.ms/3V26l0I which is sadly behind the NYT paywall, but the relevant quote is:

A Pan American World Airways spokesman said the right outboard engine
had torn loose when the craft went into a sudden spin during a
deliberate demonstration of minimum control speed.  He said the pilot
had righted the plane immediately at 8,000 feet and had flown to
Lon[d]on on three engines with no difficulty.

I'm having trouble believing a 707 can recover from a spin.  A wing drop, sure, but recovering from a fully developed spin seems implausible.  Unfortunately, I've been unable to find anything that doesn't just refer back to this UPI article.  Anybody know anything more about this incident?
I'm also astounded that the crew would fly 230 miles back to London instead of landing at the nearest runway after having an engine torn off the plane, but maybe that's just how pilots did things in 1959.

egad! That aircraft came to a grizzly end too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_214

A spokesman for an airline might say the recognizable "spin" instead of the precise but unrecognizable jargon "spiral dive" which is easier to recover from.  Answers to https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/753/31425 confirm your hunch that the 707 couldn't recover from a true spin.  Welcome to Aviation SE!
